# Save text of textarea in db

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, textarea

the problem is as follows

- I've got to save the contents of a textarea taken from a html page
- send it with an $.ajax call to a php file
- write to the db the contets of textarea
- with another php file read the contents of textarea from the DB without losing the formatting of the text
- display the recovered text in another textarea

example

save

hello
hello
hello

display

hello
hello
hello

and not hellohellohello

I tried like this, but I lose the formatting of the text

my html page

```
<textarea id="materiale1" style="margin-top: 0px;width: 715px;height:70px;max-width:715px;max-height:70px;" class="k-textbox"></textarea>

<a href="#" onclick="scrivi();return false;"><span class='k-button' style="margin-top: 0px;"><h3>SCRIVI</h3></span></a>

<textarea id="materiale2" style="margin-top: 80px;width: 715px;height:70px;max-width:715px;max-height:70px;" class="k-textbox"></textarea>

<a href="#" onclick="leggi();return false;"><span class='k-button' style="margin-top: 72px;"><h3>LEGGI</h3></span></a>
```

call the function for send the textarea text to a file php

```
function scrivi(){

$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url : "test_scrivi.php?testo="+$('#materiale1').val(),
    dataType:'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(dati){ 

     }
     , error : function(errore){ 
     } 
    });
}
```

file php (test_scrivi.php) for save text of textarea

```
<?php


 try {

include('../../login/connect_db.php');

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$my_hostname;dbname=$my_db_name", $my_username, $my_password);

$testo = nl2br($_GET['testo']);

$query = "UPDATE test SET testo='".$testo."' WHERE id = 1";

$result = $db->query($query);


} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
        //echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

call the function for read the textarea text

```
function leggi(){

    $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url : "test_leggi.php",
            dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(dati_arrivati){ 

                $('#materiale2').val(dati_arrivati)

            }
            , error : function(errore){ 
              } 
        });


}
```

file php (test_leggi.php) for read the text of textarea

```
<?php


try {

    include('../../login/connect_db.php');

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$my_hostname;dbname=$my_db_name", $my_username, $my_password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1";

    $result = $db->query($query);

    header("Content-type: application/json");

    $testo = "";

    foreach($result as $row)
        {

            $testo = nl2br($row['testo']);


        } 

    echo json_encode($testo);

    $db = null;

} 
catch(PDOException $e)
{
        //echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: You're overwriting the variable `$testo` each time through the loop, so you'll only get one row instead of all of them in `test_leggi.php`.

Comment: yes, it is only a test
there is only one row in the table with id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your AJAX call to:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url : "test_scrivi.php",
    data: { testo: $('#materiale1').val() },
    dataType:'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(dati){ 

     },
    error : function(errore){ 
     } 
});
```

You weren't properly URL-encoding the value. When you use a data object, jQuery does this correctly.

Comment: perfect, the problem was in the ajax call

At this point I removed the function nl2br

thank you!

Comment: You still need `nl2br`, because when you put the value back in `HTML` it needs the markup.

Comment: I think the problem is in the view. where you call : echo json_encode($testo);